# table schema to datatable c#

Tags: c#

How do I read a schema into datatable in c#

```
<header>
  <xs:schema id="header" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="header" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="enteredon" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="enteredby" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="remark" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
</header>
```

Trying this code but fails:

```
 public static Stream StringToStream(string data)
 {
     try
     {
        System.IO.MemoryStream xmlStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xmlStream);
        writer.Write(data);
        writer.Flush();
        return xmlStream;
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         return null;
     }
 }

table.ReadXmlSchema(StringToStream(saveData));
```

Comment: When you say fails, what do you mean exactly?  Does it throw an exception?  Does it read a portion of the schema?  Does it crash silently, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will thrown "Root Element is missing" exception.

I found a solution in [DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/236068), which is to add below codes to reset the position.

```
    System.IO.MemoryStream xmlStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xmlStream);
    writer.Write(data);
    writer.Flush();
    xmlStream.Position = 0;//Add this to reset the position of the stream.
```

Please try again.

Comment: you are awesome, that's the exact error I was getting and setting the position to 0 did the trick. Thanks.